# CasperJS - How to open up in parallel all links from an array of links

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I need to open all the links of the array in parallel.
How to make it?
In my code, all links will be open one by one, instead of parallel.
Here is my code:

```
casper.then(function(){
     links = this.evaluate(function(){
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        links = Array.prototype.map.call(links,function(link){
        return link.getAttribute('href');
        });
        return links;
    });
});
casper.then(function(){
    this.each(links,function(self,link){
     self.thenOpen(link,function(a){
     this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
     });
    });
});
casper.run(function(){this.exit()});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `casper` object represents a single browser window.

One approach is to create multiple `casper` objects, one per URL you want to get in parallel. Note that [this is not officially supported](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/Scx4Cjqp7hE/discussion), and so may be fragile.

Another approach is to use a bash script to start multiple instances of `casperjs`, and give each of them a set of the URLs to fetch. This is nice and clean (if using persistent cookies, you might want to make sure they each have their own cookie file: `--cookies-file=/path/to/cookies.txt`), but might be harder for you to script, depending on how you were getting your initial list of URLs.